# Laravel - Adding back slash to array after edit

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my controller:

```
$sql = Raid::findOrFail($request['id']);
$sql = $sql->update($request->all());
```

I have a array in my table , after update value will be like this:

```
"{\"Plate\":0,\"Cloth\":0,\"Mail\":0,\"Leather\":0}"
```

but it should be:

```
{"Plate":"0","Cloth":"0","Mail":"0","Leather":"0"}
```

so I will get an error

before this , I was updating like this and it was ok:

```
$sql = Raid::where('id', $request['id'])->update($request->all());
```

and this is my model (traders and class_traders is fields that I have problem with):

```
    use SoftDeletes;

    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $table = 'raid';

    protected $dates = ['date_and_time','deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
      'admin_id', '....
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'bosses' => 'array',
        'traders' => 'array',
        'class_traders' => 'array',
        'boosters' => 'array',
    ];
```

Comment: `"{\"Plate\":0,\"Cloth\":0,\"Mail\":0,\"Leather\":0}"` is how arrays are saved to the database; in JSON format. What error do you get with this?

Comment: my previous data is without \ and it's working , when it has a \ I will get an error because I'm not decoding/encoding it and it's working for me

Comment: What error, specifically, are you getting with this code? What code is throwing the error?

Comment: this is the error: ```Invalid argument supplied for foreach()``` and this is the code: ```@foreach ($v->traders as $t => $k)```

Comment: I know why it's happening but I have data on my server and I don't want to change all of them just because of these , isn't there any way to remove the back slashes?

Comment: Hmm, I see. You can do a database-level replace on those columns, replacing the slash with `''` (empty), but you'd have to figure out the syntax, and also debug why your code is intserting them. I'm looking at a local project, and I have mix of arrays with and without the slash.

Comment: but it's not working for me if I have mixed data :D I have to fix it with code , I don't why it's like this if do it like this ```$sql = Raid::findOrFail($request['id']);``` ```$sql = $sql->update($request->all());```

Comment: Well, for starters, `Raid::findOrFail()` returns a Model instance, which uses those defined `casts` attributes, but `Raid::update()` does not; it performs an Eloquent DB-level update, so that could explain why one has the slashes and why one doesn't.

Comment: so what should I do? I need to call the model first , i've even tried to encode and decode the array but i've got the same error

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not sure for your case. I guess stick with the approach that doesn't generate the slashes, and do a database-level replace to fix the columns, like I suggested earlier. I don't know what DB language you're using (MySQL, Postgres, etc), but lookup how to do a string replace and try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is don't update the model using the `update($request->all())` way, but you need to specify each of the field's value. For the JSON field, you could try using `json_encode()` to save it.

That should do it.